# how to transfer datatable data to datagridview with specific number in textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I have DataGridView with three columns and four textboxes. i want to transfer same first three textboxes data rows to  DataGridView as number input in fourth textbox. for example if I input 4 in textbox 4 then four times same row should be inserted in  DataGridView but it should not delete old rows entered before.

[image]

```
    dt.Columns.Add("number")
    dt.Columns.Add("name")
    dt.Columns.Add("lastname")


    dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text, TextBox3.Text})

    Dim pageNum As Integer = 1

    Dim pageSize As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text.Trim())

    Dim dtPage As DataTable = dt.Rows.Cast(Of System.Data.DataRow)().Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).CopyToDataTable()

    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    DataGridView1.datasource = dtpage
```

Comment: I'm guessing here dt is a datatable.  If so, you should have a read up on the NewRow method.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.newrow?view=net-5.0  Then it's simply a case of looping it for the desired number of iterations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to keep adding rows to a `DataTable` that will show up in the DataGridView. You want the same data repeated the number of times it appears in `TextBox4`.

I created a `Form` level variable for the `DataTable` so the same table can be accessed each time Button1 is clicked. I set up the columns in the `Form.Load` and bound the grid to the `DataTable`.

In `Button1` I looped the number of times entered in `TextBox4`, adding a row on each iteration with identical data. This is automatically displayed in the grid.

```
Private dt As New DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With dt.Columns
        .Add("Number")
        .Add("Name")
        .Add("LastName")
    End With
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For counter = 1 To CInt(TextBox4.Text)
        dt.Rows.Add({TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text})
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is working flawless. thanks a lot.